# Executing docker with php and then use other container in command

Tags: docker

I'm using docker for php and another one for sql. Also I have a makefile to run commands in a instance of this container. This is the entry I use for command execution, and I would like to use sql container I have.

```
command:
    docker run --rm \
    --volume=${PWD}/code:/code \
    --volume=${PWD}/json:/json:rw \
    --volume=${PWD}/file:/file:rw \
    own_php:latest \
    time php /code/public/index_hex.php ${page}
```

If I try to execute this command from the make file, I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name does not resolve

This is the docker-compose I have in my project

```
version: '3'
services:
  sql:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./init-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./.mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/
  crawler:
    build:
      context: './docker-base'
    depends_on:
      - sql
    volumes:
      - ./json:/json:rw
      - ./file:/file:rw
      - ./code:/code
```

But if I run the container using my docker-composer, and I enter inside the container the command executes well.

It is possible for `docker run --rm` to use another container?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Compose [creates a network for each compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you have to attach your manually `docker run` container to that network to be able to reach other containers on it.  The network will usually be named something like `directoryname_default`, based on the name of the directory holding the compose file, and it will show up in the `docker network ls` listing.

You should run something like

```
docker run --rm --net directoryname_default ...
```